# Converting a bitlocked Windows PC to a VM

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v

I have a Windows 10 bit locked pc. I can remove the BitLocker but do I need to do that before converting to a VM? I've attempted a couple of times to convert this laptop already but it doesn't boot (I've converted other laptops without issues so I'm familiar with the process... usually). In the past, I used MS disk2vhd, gen 1, shadow copy and then use HyperV to run the VM later. On the one that keeps failing to boot, I can access the VM as a vhd so the content is there. Based on this, is it a BitLocker issue or simply a configuration setting preventing it from booting? I do not get any error message displayed to the screen, it is just a black screen with a blinking underline cursor.

Answer (score 0):

If it is properly bitlocked, you MUST remove the lock first - it is stored in a secure element that cna not be virtualized. You can have a secure VM (with a simulated virtual secure element) but - that is a NEW element, there is no way to get a key out of a secure element. That is the whole concept behind them - to make sure something secret stays secret.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. It made sense it might be the issue but when I was able to access the vhd, it caused me to scratch my head for a bit. I'll unlock it and try again.

Comment: @TomTom By secure element that can not be virtualized you mean TPM? Not all computers have that